# Foreach loading fields values of and object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach

Learning with C#, SQlite and Entity Framework.

Class Usuario

```
public partial class Usuario
{
    private DbSet<Usuario> usuarios;

    public Usuario(DbSet<Usuario> usuarios)
    {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Reminder { get; set; }
}
```

I want to loop trough all the registries on the table `Usuario` and show some fields concatenated on a MessageBox (console will be the same)

My code:

```
using (var db = new MyBDEntities())
{
    foreach (Usuario usuarios in db.Usuarios)
    {
        Usuario ActualUser = new Usuario();

        var nameActualUser = ActualUser.Name;
        var passActualUser = ActualUser.Password;
        var reminderActualUser = ActualUser.Reminder;

        MessageBox.Show("Reading info from: " + nameActualUser + " - "  + passActualUser + " - " + reminderActualUser);
    }
}
```

But I know I miss something on the line

```
Usuario ActualUser = new Usuario();
```

because Visual Studio says

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'usuarios'

I don't know how to "load" the full registry / Object into a new one to handle the fields. Thanks

Comment: your data is inside `usuarios`  ... where do you use it? Thats your foreach variable. You create a `new Usuario()` named `ActualUser` instead and use that one ... makes not much sense, does it?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner Now I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the actual iteration variable should solve your problem:

```
foreach (Usuario usuarios in db.Usuarios)
{ 
    var nameActualUser = usuarios.Name;
    var passActualUser = usuarios.Password;
    var reminderActualUser = usuarios.Reminder;

    MessageBox.Show("Reading info from: " + nameActualUser + " - "  + passActualUser + " - " + reminderActualUser); 
}
```

If you need the data elsewhere, you could instanciate a list outside of the loop and stuff the needed users inside it...

Comment: Now I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" on the "in" keyword

Comment: Is `db.Usarios` a getter/setter of a property or a function? if the latter you might need to add **`()`** to the call ...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question, the class Usuario is posted on the top.

Comment: `db.Usarios` - is it a Property of your `MyBDEntities` or is it implemented as function inside `MyBDEntities` - if it is a function you call it by `db.Usarios()` - not `db.Usarios`

Comment: OK, On the Model Browser Usuario is under Entity Type so I think it's a Property of MyBDEntities. Now it's working, thanks for the support